# how to loop over pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, loops, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a python function which works on sequence of coordinates (trajectory data). It requires data to be in the following format.

```
#items = [Item(x1, y1), Item(x2, y2), Item(x3, y3), Item(x4, y4)]
items = [Item(0.5, 0.5), Item(-0.5, 0.5), Item(-0.5, -0.5), Item(0.5, -0.5)]
```

It is also required to find the xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax from the above **items** and specify it for a bounding box as below.

```
 spindex = pyqtree.Index(bbox=[-1, -1, 1, 1])
                        #bbox = [xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax]
```

Now, the items are inserted as below.

```
 #Inserting items
 for item in items:
     spindex.insert(item, item.bbox)
```

As we can see for now all the above operations are performed on a single sequence of coordinates specified in **items**. I require to perform the above steps on a data frame with multiple trajectories, each having multiple sequence of points and identified by an id **vid**.

The sample df is as follows:

```
   vid       x         y
0  1         2         3
1  1         3         4
2  1         5         6
3  2         7         8 
4  2         9        10
5  3         11       12
6  3         13       14
7  3         15       16
8  3         17       18
```

In the above data frame, x, y are the coordinate data and all the points belonging to the same “vid" forms one separate trajectory; so it can be observed rows(0-2) belonging to voyage id (vid) = 1 is one trajectory, while points belonging to vid = 2 is another trajectory and so on.

The above data can be transformed as the following df too (only if required):

```
    vid        (x,y)
0   1          [ (2,3),(3,4), (5,6) ]
1   2          [ (7,8),(9,10) ]
2   3          [ (11,12),(13,14),(15,16),(17,18) ]
```

I want to create a way to loop over the df and maybe groupby them with **vid** and get all the coordinates as **items** and find xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax and insert them as shown above for each of the trajectories in the df.

I have a code something like this, but it doesn't works

```
for group in df.groupby('vid'):
bbox = [ group['x'].min(), group['y'].min(), group['x'].max(), group['y'].max() ]
spindex.insert(group['vid'][0], bbox)
```

Please Help.

Comment: @jezrael Can you please kindly help me here with this problem.

Comment: @piRSquared Kindly please help me here. I have also posted the detailed question if required : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232622/how-to-perform-quadtree-operation-on-pandas-data-frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gourpby return ((gkeys), grouped_dataframe)
Modify your codes to following:

```
for g in df.groupby('vid'):
   vid = g[0]
   g_df = g[1]
   bbox = [ g_df['x'].min(), g_df['y'].min(), g_df['x'].max(), g_df['y'].max() ]
   spindex.insert(vid, bbox)
```

Comment: Thank you. But I am getting a NameError that name "g" is not defined, so if I am defining g = [ ] before, I get and IndexError, list index out of range.

Comment: Edited the answer, please try again.